# Using Excel transpose data from column to row whilst also finding uniques

Tags: excel

I have what seems to be an easy task but at the minute i'm stumped.
I have a list of text values, say A1:A19, with multiple entries some of which are repeated in the list.
I want to take the list in column A and copy to a row, say B2:B8, However i only want to move across each individual value once. Can this be done?

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/82888/257568) help?

Comment: In Excel 365 you can use `=UNIQUE(A1:A19)`

Comment: I've tried the unique function but that puts the results in a column format when i need a row

Comment: Sorry... your question said you wanted it pasted in B2:B8 as an example which is a single column, to transpose to a row use `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A1:A19))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UNIQUE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e) returns the unique values from a range.
[TRANSPOSE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-function-ed039415-ed8a-4a81-93e9-4b6dfac76027) rotates cells from rows to columns or vice-versa.

`=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A2:A19))`

[image]

Comment: Thank you Darren that's exactly what I'm after. How do I send you a rep increase to increase you're rating?

Comment: Should be a greyed out tick at the top left of my answer - just tick it as the accepted answer. :)